# how to access a csv file which i saved in a colab project to another colab project

Tags: dataframe, csv, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

Help regarding colab project.
i am working on walmart sales prediction and i have created the required dataframe in a colab file, now for prediction of future sales i need to access that file and if i do that in the same colab file then the size being big the ram crashes... so i am thinking of accessing it in another colab file. How to do it and i dont want to download the file and upload it in that colab project.

```
df.to_csv('wm_sales.csv')
```

i have saved the file and its showing in my folder in colab and now i want to use it in another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply mount your google drive disk and save any files in the specified directory:

[image]

Comment: i have mounted my drive to access the files needed for the 1st colab file but then how to access the output file in another colab project as the output file isn't there on colab

Comment: You should save the output file in the Google Drive directory: 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/wm_sales.csv'. Then this file will be available for any your notebook, while you are using the same google account.

Comment: You are welcome! I would appreciate it if you mark the answer as the solution.